# VichUploaderBundle - PropertyAccessor requires a graph of objects or arrays to operate on, but it found type "NULL"

Tags: symfony4, vichuploaderbundle

i try to make this bundle running with Form.

First this is my entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Entity\File as EmbeddedFile;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BanqueRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Banque
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $libelle;

    /**
     * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
     * 
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="banques_image", fileNameProperty="image.name", size="image.size", mimeType="image.mimeType", originalName="image.originalName", dimensions="image.dimensions")
     * 
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Embedded(class="Vich\UploaderBundle\Entity\File")
     *
     * @var EmbeddedFile
     */
    private $image;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLibelle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->libelle;
    }

    public function setLibelle(string $libelle): self
    {
        $this->libelle = $libelle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
     * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the  update. If this
     * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
     * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
     * during Doctrine hydration.
     *
     * @param File|UploadedFile $image
     */
    public function setImageFile(?File $image = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $image;

        if (null !== $image) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }
    }

    public function getImageFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    public function setImage(EmbeddedFile $image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    public function getImage(): ?EmbeddedFile
    {
        return $this->image;
    }
}
```

and the "Form" for this entity :

```
<?php
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Banque;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;


class BanqueType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('libelle', TextType::class)
            ->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Banque::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

and now the most simplest controller ;)

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Banque;
use App\Form\BanqueType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class BanqueController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/banque/add", name="banque_add")
     */
    public function add(Request $request)
    {
        $banque = new Banque();
        $form = $this->createForm(BanqueType::class, $banque, array('action' => $this->generateUrl('banque_add')));

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $banque = $form->getData();

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($banque);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
        }

        return $this->render(
            'banque/form.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView(),
                'icone'=> 'mdi-plus',
                'text' => 'Création'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

But when i go to "/banque/add" i have an exception :

PropertyAccessor requires a graph of objects or arrays to operate on, but it found type "NULL" while trying to traverse path "image.name" at property "name".

I know somthing is wrong but i don't found what it is. Any help will be appreciate !

thanks all,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add the initialization to your entity:

**e.g:**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->image = new EmbeddedFile();
}
```